# Cannot convert Type `ClassA` to T

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I'm writeing a generice method in C#:

```
private T GetMamConfigurations<T>(IDictionary<string, object> items,
                                  MaMDBEntities maMDBEntities) where T : class
{
    T geoConfigs = default(T);
    if (typeStr.Equals("MamConfiguration", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        geoConfigs = (T)GetGeoConfigurationNumericFromDB(items, maMDBEntities);
    }
    else if (typeStr.Equals("ListOfMamConfiguration", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        geoConfigs = (T)GetGeoConfigurationsPercentageFromDB(items, maMDBEntities);
    }

    return geoConfigs;
}
```

`GetGeoConfigurationNumericFromDB` returns `MamConfiguration`

whereas

`GetGeoConfigurationsPercentageFromDB` returns `IList<MamConfiguration>`

and I get compliation error:

> *cannot cast expression of type `MamConfiguration` to type `T`*

Why is that?

Is there any way to solve without forcinf the two methods to return `IList<MamConfiguration>` ?

Comment: Please take more care formatting code in your posts in future. Look at the preview before you post, and consider whether that's *really* what you want people to see.

Comment: Why doesn't your method return either `MamConfiguration` or `IEnumerable<MamConfiguration>`? (By either wrapping a single result in a list in the first branch or getting the first item in the second branch.) The code looks odd to me and it seems all it does is obscure the cause of a `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `(T)` to cast to `T`, you can use the `as` operator. `as` will return `null` if the conversion fails. If it succeeds, it will return your converted value.

```
geoConfigs = GetGeoConfigurationNumericFromDB(items, maMDBEntities) as T;
```

Comment: Personally I'd say that a regular cast is preferable here. Much easier to debug an obvious type-cast fail (with a message that includes the 2 types) than it is to debug a random null-ref without any context.

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree.. but the whole method is strange. It returns completely different values depending on a string value. But isn't an extra null check that throws an exception telling you, you are calling the method with an invalid type clearer then a cast exception?

Comment: Ehm.. it does have a class constraint?

Comment: oops, I missed the class constraint. My bad. Re the other: sure - but then you need to add the code that does a null check that throws an exception telling you that you are calling the method with an invalid type :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always *placate* the compiler by adding an `object` cast in the middle:

```
geoConfigs = (T)(object)GetGeoConfigurationNumericFromDB(items, maMDBEntities);
```

which will defer the type-check until runtime. However! There is no compiler way to do this otherwise, as it is never going to be happy with string tests like `"MamConfiguration"`. Also, generics work well when the code is ... *generic* - i.e. does the same thing which each type. The code shown is the opposite of *generic*. It is non-generic code exposed through a generic API. It is always going to be messy inside. Personally I would try to avoid this usage in the first place.